# How do I authenticate a user on laravel + Vs code + flutter?

Tags: laravel, flutter, authentication, visual-studio-code

I'm able to register a new user and save in my database, but unable to login, I get a 'Forbidden error : 403' whenever I try to login,

Relevant Code block below:

**Sign-in Page**

```
authController.login(email, password).then((status){
          if(status.isSuccess){
            print("We're In!");
            Get.toNamed(RouteHelper.getInitial());

          }else{
            print("Failed To Login "+status.toString());
            showCustomSnackBar(status.message);
          }
```

**authController**

```
Future<ResponseModel> login(String email,String password) async{
    _isLoading = true;
    update();
    Response response = await authRepo.login(email, password);
    late ResponseModel responseModel;
    if (response.statusCode == 200){
      print("Backend token");
      authRepo.saveUserToken(response.body["token"]);
      print(response.body["token"].toString());
      responseModel = ResponseModel(true, response.body["token"]);

    }else{
      responseModel = ResponseModel(false, response.statusText!);
      print("Unsuccessful retrieval of token from Server: " + response.statusCode.toString());
    }
```

I tried using postman to send a Post request, I thought I wasn't receiving the token, but I'm able to retrieve a Token successfully.

By the way, I'm working on a localhost for now with Laravel backend + VS Code + Flutter, what could be the problem?

Comment: 'I thought I wasn't receiving the token but I'm able to retrieve a Token successfully.' Do you recieve the token or not?  --> he website owner edited the settings so that you couldn't access the resources, or they didn't set the correct permissions.

Comment: I do, from PostMan but in app no, I don't.

Comment: Do you use Postman Agent? or the website?

Comment: I use postMan Agent

Answer (score 1):

This should work i think you forgot to define username to the variable

`'username'` <--[api] `: username` <--[variable]`,`

authController

```
Future<ResponseModel> login(String email,String password) async{
    _isLoading = true;
    update();
    
    Response response = await authRepo.login, body: {
      'username': username,
      'password': password,
    });
    late ResponseModel responseModel;
    if (response.statusCode == 200){
      print("Backend token");
      authRepo.saveUserToken(response.body["token"]);
      print(response.body["token"].toString());
      responseModel = ResponseModel(true, response.body["token"]);

    }else{
      responseModel = ResponseModel(false, response.statusText!);
      print("Unsuccessful retrieval of token from Server: " + response.statusCode.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Just gave it a try, same error results...